# Django with Apache Webserver on Ubuntu Server: Trying to login with Active Directory Users

Tags: python, django, ldap

i'm trying to authenticate my django users via the ldap interface of the domain controller.
My test code worked successfully to contact the active directory. But configuring django to accept this didn't work till now. My test to login with the browser at Hostname/admin did not work:
Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive. Are my settings at settings.py correct and do I have to activate them for django (or apache)?
Which username should I use for login at django login? Like in windows login?
python manage.py check brings no failures.

Here is my settings.py excerpt:

```
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch, GroupOfNamesType

AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://<IP Adress>"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "cn=<existing_bind_user>,ou=<xxx>,dc=<domain>,dc=com"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "<password>"
AUTH_LDAP_USER_DN_TEMPLATE = 'sAMAccountName=%(user)s,ou=<xxx>,dc=<domain>,dc=com'

#Inside the ou "Django" are the 3 different groups G_Django_Admin,G_Django_User,...
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=Django,ou=<xxx>,dc=<domain>,dc=com",ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,"(objectClass=groupOfNames)",)
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = GroupOfNamesType(name_attr="cn")

AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    "username": "sAMAccountName",
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail"}

AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
    "is_active": "cn=G_Django_User,ou=Django,ou=<xxx>,dc=<domain>,dc=com",
    "is_staff": "cn=G_Django_Staff,ou=Django,ou=<xxx>,dc=<domain>,dc=com",
    "is_superuser": "cn=G_Django_Admin,ou=Django,ou=<xxx>,dc=<domain>,dc=com",
}

AUTH_LDAP_ALWAYS_UPDATE_USER = True
AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUP_PERMS = True
AUTH_LDAP_CACHE_TIMEOUT = 3600
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend",
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
)
```

Best regards
Berni